# Suddenly lost permissions to read values in Real-time database Firebase-console

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Out of the blue, I lost permission to one of my real-time databases in Firebase. I can still view usage statistics but I cannot read the date in the database (through the database)

Image showing the message I get when I press "Realtime database"
[image]

Image showing how I still can view usage.
[image]

I can still access my other projects with no problem. I have not switched accounts etc. Whether my app can read/write to the database I do not know.

The project is just used to learn Firebase. So I can create a new one. But that doesn't explain why this happened in the first place.

### Can anyone shed any light on why this might have happend?

Comment: Unless there's another owner on the project who changes your permissions, it's unlikely someone here can say what happened. It might be a good idea to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

The next day I refreshed the page once again, and it was back to normal.

For anyone who encounters this in the future.